# Matrix with complex exponential elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, complex-numbers

I have been trying to create this Hamiltonian matrix, and I believe the complex exponential elements are giving me trouble. However, I don't know how to fix it.

This is what I have written so far:

```
t = 2.7
a = 1

z = -t * np.exp(-j*k*a)

y = -t * np.exp(j*k*a)

H = np.matrix(([0, -t,0,-t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [- t, 0,- t ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0, - t ,0,y,0,-t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [-t, 0,z,0,-t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0, 0,0,- t ,0,- t ,0,-t,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0, 0,-t,0,0,-t,0,-t,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,- t ,0,y,0,-t,0,0,0,0]
    [0, 0,0,0,-t,0,z,0,- t,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,- t,0,- t,0,-t,0,0]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,0,-t,0,- t,0,- t,0,0,0]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,- t,0,y,0,-t]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-t,0,z,0,- t,0]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,- t ,0,- t]
    [0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-t,0,- t ,0]),dtype = np.complex)`
```

When I try to run the cell, this error message appears

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

The matrix needs to be a 14x14 one so that I can code and obtain the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

In the past I have used np.array to build matrices, and it has worked fine. However, for this one it didn't. As can be seen, I have also tried using np.matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
np.array([[val1, val2], [val3, val4]])
```

instead of

```
np.array(([val1, val2] [val3, val4])) ...
```

You got the error because of the commas in between the rows. Don't forget them otherwise Python thinks you are trying to do list indexing:

I.e.

```
[1,2,3][0] 
Output: 1
```

Whereas

```
[1,2,3], [0]
```

Output:

```
([1,2,3], [0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried that and it still outputs the same error message.

Comment: What is your k variable?

Comment: it is meant to be an array of values, but I have tried setting it to an integer and it still outputs the same error.

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for the sloppiness. I am on mobile :)